# Memory Leak Field Variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, memory-management, memory-leaks

I do not undserstand why I cannot simply add [sortedArray release]; at the end of this method. Everytime I do, it crashes.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSString *workoutName =  [event.assignedWorkout valueForKey:@"name"];
self.title = workoutName ;
NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Sort ExerciseArray
int y = 0;
int x= 0;
do{
    if ([[[exerciseArray objectAtIndex:y] index]intValue] == x){
        [sortedArray addObject:[exerciseArray objectAtIndex:y] ];
        x++;
        }
        if (y<[exerciseArray count]-1){
                y++;
            }else {
                y=0;
            }

}
while(x <= [exerciseArray count]-1);

exerciseArray = sortedArray;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

If anyone can point me in the right direction or refer me to some documentation, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to add `[sortedArray release]` at the end of the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the array to the `exerciseArray` variable and then you are releasing the array. The next time you try to access the `exerciseArray` variable, the array will be gone, because assigning it to the `exerciseArray` variable doesn't increase its retain count.

The array object's retain count is 1 when you first call `alloc`. When you assign it to exerciseArray, its retain value is still 1. Then, when you release it, its retain count drops to 0 and you can't expect to access the array again.

You should either not release it (my preference), or else explicitly retain it by calling:

```
[exerciseArray release];
exerciseArray = [sortedArray retain];
[sortedArray release];
```

Note the order of those two messages. The first line releases any existing object pointed to by the `exerciseArray` variable. The second line raises the new array's retain count to 2, and the second then drops it to 1, so the array is still retained. If you release `sortedArray` before assigning the new array to the `exerciseArray` variable, the retain count becomes 0 and you will lose it before you can assign it to the new variable.

Comment: exerciseArray should be released prior to being assigned a new value.

Comment: Got it! Great thanks for the detailed explanation. I am understanding MM more and more..

Comment: jojaba is right. If the exerciseArray already points to a retained object, then you should call [exerciseArray release] before assigning it a new value. Otherwise, that object will stay retained in memory as a memory leak.

Comment: And yeah, memory management can get confusing in obj-c without garbage collection. You really have to be careful and deliberate, but it's satisfying when you get a grip on it.

Comment: @Steve -- Just a note for the future: beware of thinking of retain count as an absolute number. Various of your objects may be retained without you knowing by the framework. While it's true that Apple's docs say "alloc creates retain count of 1", you should always consider only your "personal" retain count -- how many claims of ownership have you made, and how many have you relinquished -- not speculate about the "real" value of the object's count. (aside to @Charlie: not to say that you were suggesting this; just an addendum.)

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to do:

```
[exerciseArray release];
exerciseArray = sortedArray;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

BTW, you can sort an Array using a block with sortedArrayUsingComparator.

Comment: I need exerciseArray for my didSelectAtIndexPath method later on. I tried releasing it and still got a crash. Instruments keeps pointing to sortedArray.

Comment: Instruments point at the array you have allocated. The line "exerciseArray = sortedArray;" is problematic. You need to release the previous exerciseArray like I proposed in the answer above, or upon assignment (and it's only assigns a pointer), you'll loose the reference to the previous contents and effectively leak them. When you assign (and DON'T release the sortedArray, as both point to the same memory), you'll be able to use exerciseArray later on.

Comment: @SteveBay22: This is correct, but by way of explanation: you don't _want_ to release `sortedArray`, because your assignment to `exerciseArray` does not increase the number of retains you have on it. When you `alloc` `sortedArray`, you have one, and when you assign that object to a new name, you still have one. If you release it under either name, you no longer have ownership and can't complain if it is deallocated out from under you. :)

Comment: I just read over Memory Management Programming Guide from Apple, very helpful. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html